# Characteristic function issue

Tags: probability, expected-value, sum, characteristic-function, taylor-series

As mentioned in a previous post, I've been trying to work through ALL of the problems in Jacod and Protter's *Probability Essentials*. The following problem has been giving me issues:

> Let $Z \sim N(0,1)$. Show that $E[X^{2n+1}]=0$ and $E[X^{2n}]=\frac{(2n)!}{2^n n!}$

The issue I'm having is proceeding form my Taylor Expansion for $\varphi_{_Z}(u)$. Here's my work:

> Since we're dealing with $N(0,1)$, we have
>   $$\varphi_{_Z}(u)=e^{-\frac{1}{2}u^2}$$
>   Recalling that the Taylor expansion of $e^x$ wrapped around 0, we have
>   $$\varphi_{_Z}(u)=e^{-\frac{1}{2}u^2}=\sum_{k\geq0}(-\frac{u^2}{2})^k\cdot\frac{1}{k!}=\sum_{k\geq 0}(-1)^k\frac{u^{2k}}{2^kk!}$$
>   $$\implies \varphi_{_Z}(u)=\sum_{k\geq 0}(-1)^k\frac{u^{2k}}{2^kk!}$$
>   Next, recall by a theorem in the book that
>   $$\frac{d^m}{du^m}\varphi_{_Z}(0)=i^mE[Z^m]$$
>   where $i\in \mathbb{C}$. It follows that
>   $$\frac{d^{2k}}{du^{2k}}\varphi_{_Z}(0)=\sum_{k\geq0}(-1)^k\frac{(2k)!}{2^k k!}=i^{2k}E[Z^{2k}]$$
>   and
>   $$\frac{d^{2k+1}}{du^{2k+1}}\varphi_{_Z}(0)=\sum_{k\geq0}(-1)^k(0)=0$$
>   Since $(-1)^k=i^{2k}$, it follows that we have
>   $$\sum_{k\geq0}i^{2k}\frac{(2k)!}{2^k k!}=i^{2k}E[Z^{2k}]$$
>   $$\implies E[X^{2k}]=\frac{(2k)!}{2^k k!}$$

Is it justified to get rid of the sum? I'm basically at the answer, but keeping the sum is killing me. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You made a mistake while differentiating. Notice 
\begin{align}
\varphi_{_Z}(u)&=\sum_{k\geq 0}(-1)^k\frac{u^{2k}}{2^kk!}\\
&=\frac{u^{0}}{2^00!}-\frac{u^{2}}{2^11!}+\dotsb+(-1)^{n}\frac{u^{2n}}{2^nn!}+(-1)^{n+1}\frac{u^{2(n+1)}}{2^{n+1}(n+1)!}+\dotsb,
\end{align}
So
\begin{align}\frac{d^{2n}}{du^{2n}}\varphi_{_Z}(0)&=0+0+\dotsb+(-1)^{n}\frac{(2n)!0^0}{2^nn!}+(-1)^{n+1}\frac{(2(n+1))!0^{2}}{2^{n+1}(n+1)!}+\dotsb\\
&=(-1)^{n}\frac{(2n)!}{2^nn!}.
\end{align}
That is, $$(-1)^{n}\frac{(2n)!}{2^nn!}=i^{2n}E[Z^{2n}],$$ such that $$E[Z^{2n}]=\frac{(2n)!}{2^n n!}$$ follows immediately.